# How to disable only selected button onClick inside .map() function of REACT js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, setstate, map-function

I have shopping Application in **REACT** js. Im displaying all products using .map() function, and also showing "ADD to CART" button  infront of each product. When **ADD to Cart** btn is clicked, it adds the clicked product ID in local storage then I display these selected products in **Shopping** **Cart** by retrieving IDs from **localStorage**. It all works **fine**.

Now what I wanted is to disable the "ADD to Cart" button(for selected product only) when its clicked Once. I did it by setting state **but it actually Disables ALL "ADD to Cart" Buttons** infront of all PRODUCTS *instead* of disabling only selected button.

I searched this issue alot, and the soltion I got everywhere is just to **setState** to true/false to enable/disable button. I did it but no use because its doing it for **ALL** products on that Page. Please help me what to do.

Here is my REACT JS code:

```js
export default class SpareParts extends Component
{
  constructor()
  {
      super()
      this.state = {
        spareParts: [],
        cart: [],
        inCart: false,
        disabledButton: false
      };

      this.ViewDeets = this.ViewDeets.bind(this);
      this.AddToCart = this.AddToCart.bind(this);
  }


  ViewDeets= function (part)
  {
    this.props.history.push({
                pathname: '/partdetails',
                 state: {
                    key: part
                }
            });
  }

  AddToCart(param, e)
  {
  
    var alreadyInCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItem")) || [];
    alreadyInCart.push(param);
    localStorage.setItem("cartItem", JSON.stringify(alreadyInCart));

    this.setState({
      inCart: true,
      disabledButton: true
    })

  }

  
  componentDidMount()
  {
    console.log("Showing All Products to Customer");

        axios.get('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/all_parts.php', {
        headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }} )
       .then(response =>
       {
       this.setState({
              spareParts :response.data.records
            });
       })
         .catch(error => {
         if (error) {
           console.log("Sorry Cannot Show all products to Customer");
           console.log(error);
         }
           });
  }

render()
  {
    return (

<div id="profileDiv">

{this.state.spareParts.map(  part =>


<Col md="3" lg="3" sm="6" xs="6">
  <Card>

  <Image src={"data:image/png[jpg];base64," +  part.Image}
  id="partImg" alt="abc" style={ {width: "90%"}} />

  <h4>  {part.Name} </h4>
  <h5> Rs. {part.Price}  </h5>
  <h5> {part.Make} {part.Model} {part.Year} </h5>
  <h5> {part.CompanyName} </h5>

<button
    onClick={()=> this.ViewDeets(part) }>
    View Details
</button>

<button onClick={() => this.AddToCart(part.SparePartID)}
   
   disabled={this.state.disabledButton ? "true" : ""}>
  {!this.state.inCart ? ("Add to Cart") : "Already in Cart"}
</button>

  </Card>
</Col>

)}

</div>

);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you only need to disable one button at a time? If so, change your state to be not a boolean but a number indicating which button is disabled. Then in render, only disable if the button you're rendering has the same index as found in the state.

```
this.state = {
   disabledButton: -1
   // ...
}

// ...

AddToCart(index, param, e) {
  //...
  this.setState({
    inCart: true,
    disabledButton: index
  })
}


// ...

{this.state.spareParts.map((part, index) => {
   // ...
  <button onClick={() => this.AddToCart(index, part.SparePartID)}
    disabled={this.state.disabledButton === index}>
    {!this.state.inCart ? ("Add to Cart") : "Already in Cart"}
  </button>
})}
```

If instead each button needs to be independently disableable at the same time, change your state to be an array of booleans with the same length as the spare parts, and in the render method have each button look up whether it should be disabled in that array.

```
this.state = {
  spareParts: [],
  disabledButtons: [],
  // ...
}

// ...

axios.get('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/all_parts.php', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }} )
.then(response =>{
  this.setState({
    spareParts: response.data.records,
    disabledButtons: new Array(response.data.records.length).fill(false)
  });
});

// ...

AddToCart(index, param, e) {
  //...
  this.setState(oldState => {
    const newDisabledButtons = [...oldState.disabledButtons];
    newDisabledButtons[index] = true;
    return {
      inCart: true,
      disabledButtons: newDisabledButtons,
    }
  });
}

// ...

{this.state.spareParts.map((part, index) => {
   // ...
  <button onClick={() => this.AddToCart(index, part.SparePartID)}
    disabled={this.state.disabledButtons[index]>
    {!this.state.inCart ? ("Add to Cart") : "Already in Cart"}
  </button>
})}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes I want to disable each button independently at the same time. So how do I change state to array of booleans? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @YellowMinion I've added in an example with an array

Comment: Thanks Again. How do I get that clicked button disabled in AddToCart method?

Comment: You set the state with an array that has that index toggled to true. I've edited in an example.

Comment: Amazing and very useful answer. Exactly what I looked for but somehow I'm not getting how I could update the button immediately. I have a table with lots of buttons and they only re-render when I click out of the row instead after button click. Any tips how to trigger the re-rendering of the button which should now be disabled?