# enable and disable the onClick() function by the specific id in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created the custom **collapse & expand toggle menu** and it's map in the view corresponding to the API data. according to API data collapse menu is repeating. But when i click on first collapse menu then second collapse menu is also enable due to common function. how can i handle it that open the specific collapse menu whenever i click on it.

code:

```
        <View style={styles.section}>
          {Routes.map((o, i) =>
            o.subarr.length > 0 ? (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleExpand}>
                  <View style={styles.section}>
                    <View style={[styles.sidebarDesign]}>
                      <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                        <Icon.SimpleLineIcons
                          name={o.icon}
                          size={heightToDp('3%')}
                          color={Color.gray}
                        />
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.barLabel}>
                        <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>
                          {o.title.toUpperCase()}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                        <Icon.SimpleLineIcons
                          name={expanded ? 'arrow-up' : 'arrow-down'}
                          size={heightToDp('3%')}
                          color={Color.grayDark}
                        />
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                {o.subarr.map((r, j) => (
                  <View>
                    {expanded && (
                      <View style={[styles.sidebarDesign]}>
                        <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                          {/* <Icon.FontAwesome
                            name={r.icon}
                            size={20}
                            color={Color.gray}
                          /> */}
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.barLabel}>
                          <Text
                            onPress={() => {
                              props.navigation.navigate(r.label);
                            }}
                            style={styles.labelStyle}>
                            {r.label.toUpperCase()}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                          {/* <Text>icon</Text> */}
                        </View>
                      </View>
                    )}
                  </View>
                ))}
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View>
                <View style={[styles.sidebarDesign]}>
                  <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                    <Icon.SimpleLineIcons
                      name={o.icon}
                      size={heightToDp('3%')}
                      color={Color.gray}
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.barLabel}>
                    <Text
                      onPress={() => {
                        props.navigation.navigate(o.label);
                      }}
                      style={styles.labelStyle}>
                      {o.title.toUpperCase()}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.barIcon}>{/* <Text>icon</Text> */}</View>
                </View>
              </View>
            ),
          )}
        </View>
```

Data :

````
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Dashboard",
    "label": "Dashboard",
    "key": "dashboard",
    "icon": "home",
    "subarr": []
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Pages",
    "label": "Pages",
    "key": "pages",
    "icon": "diamond",
    "subarr": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Tabs",
        "label": "Tabs",
        "key": "tab",
        "icon": "grid"
      },

      {
        "id": 4,
        "label": "Test",
        "key": "test",
        "icon": "adn",
        "title": "Test"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Components",
    "key": "Components",
    "label": "component",
    "icon": "notebook",

    "subarr": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "label": "Card",
        "key": "card",
        "icon": "i-card",
        "title": "Card"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Button",
        "label": "Button",
        "key": "button",
        "icon": "control-play"
      },

      {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Table",
        "label": "Table",
        "key": "table",
        "icon": "list"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Charts",
        "label": "Chart",
        "key": "chart",
        "icon": "chart"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "id": 10,
    "title": "notifications",
    "label": "User",
    "key": "user",
    "icon": "bell",
    "subarr": []
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "User profile",
    "label": "Profile",
    "key": "profile",
    "icon": "user",
    "subarr": []
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "title": "Carousel",
    "label": "Carousel",
    "key": "carousel",
    "icon": "layers",
    "subarr": []
  }
]```
````

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55734553/7610724

Comment: Maintain a selected `index` in the state and add if condition in map with `index === selectedIndex`. that's it!!

Comment: @Naren Can you brief in detail. this is function. `const toggleExpand = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    setCollapse(!expanded);
  };`

Answer (score 0):

please check this link

https://snack.expo.io/VYh8f9Fsp

```
import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import styles  from './styles'
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
      itemsList: [
        {
          item: "Seasons",
          route: "",
          icon: '',
          subItem: [     { name: "Special", find: "Special" },
            { name: "Season 12", find: "12" },
            { name: "Season 11", find: "12" },
            { name: "Explorer 2018", find: "2018" },
            { name: "Season 10", find: "10" },
            { name: "Season 9", find: "9" },
            { name: "Season 8", find: "8" },
            { name: "Season 7", find: "8" },],
        },
        { item: "Music Library", route: "PlayList", icon: '',  subItem: [     { name: "Special", find: "Special" },
            { name: "Season 12", find: "12" },
            { name: "Season 11", find: "12" },
            { name: "Explorer 2018", find: "2018" },
            { name: "Season 10", find: "10" },
            { name: "Season 9", find: "9" },
            { name: "Season 8", find: "8" },
            { name: "Season 7", find: "8" },], },
        { item: "Artists", route: "Artists", icon: '',  subItem: [     { name: "Special", find: "Special" },
            { name: "Season 12", find: "12" },
            { name: "Season 11", find: "12" },
            { name: "Explorer 2018", find: "2018" },
            { name: "Season 10", find: "10" },
            { name: "Season 9", find: "9" },
            { name: "Season 8", find: "8" },
            { name: "Season 7", find: "8" },], },
      ],
      currentIndex: -1,
      subIndex: 0,
    };
  }

  handelSelection = (index) => {
    var itemsList_Clone = this.state.itemsList;
    // itemsList_Clone[index]["selected"] = !itemsList_Clone[index]["selected"];
    this.setState({ currentIndex: index, itemsList: itemsList_Clone });
  };
  subItemSelection = (index, _index) => {
    this.setState({ subIndex: index + "_" + _index });
  };
  handeSubTabSelection = (item, _index, index) => {
    this.subItemSelection(index, _index);
  };
  render() {
    const { itemsList, currentIndex, subIndex } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.container,
            styles.flex(1),
            styles.marginTop(-1),
            styles.justify_flexStart,
          ]}
        >
          <View
            style={[
              styles.menu_container,
              styles.alignItems_flexStart,
              styles.paddingHorizontal(20),
              // { fontFamily: fonts.UnityTextRegular },
              styles.menu_Row,
              styles.marginTop(10),
            ]}
          >
            
            <Text
              style={styles.menuHeading}
              // onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
            >
              {/* Dashboard */}
             Home
            </Text>
          </View>
          <ScrollView style={[{ width: "100%" }, styles.marginTop(10)]}>
            <View style={[styles.paddingHorizontal(15)]}>
              {itemsList.map((data, index) => (
                <>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    key={index}
                    onPress={() => {
                      // this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route),
                        this.handelSelection(index);
                    }}
                    style={[
                      styles.margin(5),
                      // styles.justify_spaceBetween,
                      styles.flex_Row,
                      styles.menu_Row,
                    ]}
                  >
                    <View>
                      <Image source={data.icon} style={styles.menuIcons} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={[styles.alignSelf_center]}>
                      <Text style={styles.menuHeading}>{data.item}</Text>
                    </View>
                    {index == currentIndex && (
                      <Text style={styles.menuHeading}>-</Text>
                    )}
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  {index == currentIndex &&
                    data.subItem &&
                    data.subItem.map((_item, _index) => (
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        key={_index}
                        onPress={() =>
                          this.handeSubTabSelection(_item, _index, index)
                        }
                        style={[
                          styles.margin(4),
                          styles.justify_spaceBetween,
                          styles.flex_Row,
                        ]}
                      >
                        <View>
                          <Text
                            style={[
                              styles.menuHeading,
                              styles.fontSize(16),
                              styles.UnityTextMedium,
                              styles.margin(2.5),
                              styles.paddingHorizontal(5),
                              subIndex == index + "_" + _index && {
                                color: colors.themeRed,
                              },
                            ]}
                          >
                            {_item.name}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))}
                </>
              ))}
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default (App);
```